# Any alternatives to speeding up brute force 'tally' algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, machine-learning, counting

Apologies ahead of time if this is the wrong place to post this question..if there is a better stack exchange site let me know.

So currently developing a crime prediction algorithm that essentially lays a grid over a city and predicts whether each grid entry will be a hotspot or not for the next 30 days (at least one assault crime occurs).

I am using the city of Nashville currently with a grid overlay of 3446 grids. I have a grid dataset that contains all the data needed to display the grid, the map coordinates of each grid as well as neighboring grids around it (neighbor to the bottom, neighbor to the right,..etc)

[image]

Here is an example of what the predictions look like:
[image]

In this case the green means a right prediction..red means false negative, purple means false positive for the machine learning algorithm.

To train my neural network I am using a feature set that looks like this:
[image]

Here Hotspot is the target value (either 1 and 0). Week, month year are the crime tallys from the crime incidents pulled from the last year (crime occured in last week, last month, and last year). My issue is creating these feature sets takes an extensive amount of time (script takes over 6 hours)

```
#Loop through each grid in the dataset
for grid_index, grid_row in grid.iterrows():
    print("On grid number: ", grid_row['id'])
    near=0
    #Loop through all of the crimes 
    for crime_index, crime_row in crime.iterrows():

        #Parse out the month, day, and year
        date = crime_row['Incident Occurred']
        date_pars = date.split('/')
        month = int(date_pars[0])
        day= int(date_pars[1])
        year =int(date_pars[2].split(' ')[0])

        if grid_row['top '] == crime_row['grid']:
            near +=1
        if grid_row['bottom '] == crime_row['grid']:
            near +=1
        if grid_row['left '] == crime_row['grid']:
            near +=1
        if grid_row['right '] == crime_row['grid']:
            near +=1
        if grid_row['topleft'] == crime_row['grid']:
            near +=1
        if grid_row['topright'] == crime_row['grid']:
            near +=1
        if grid_row['bottomright'] == crime_row['grid']:
            near +=1
        if grid_row['bottomleft'] == crime_row['grid']:
            near +=1

        if month == 12 and grid_row['id'] == crime_row['grid']:
            countMonth = countMonth+1
        if day >= 25 and month == 12 and grid_row['id'] == crime_row['grid']:
            countWeek = countWeek + 1

        if  year == 2017 and grid_row['id'] == crime_row['grid']:
            countYear=countYear+1

    #Update the output for the specific grid
    output = output.append({'Grid': grid_row['id'], 'Hotspot': 0, 'week': countWeek, 'month': 
    countMonth, 'year': countYear,'near': near}, ignore_index=True)
    countMonth = 0
    countYear = 0
    countWeek = 0
```

Right now this code loops through each grid (3446 total) and within each grid it loops through each crime (around 18,000) counting up the tallys and appending it to a pandas dataframe...3446*18000 is around 62 million calculations to create this dataset. I feel like this wouldn't take too long but it is taking way longer then ideally.

Any ideas on how this could be speed up efficiently? I need to run this algorithm for each month of the last three years, so 36 times at over 5 hours each run time is way too long for my time constraints.

Thanks ahead of time for any insight.

EDIT: To clarify 'grid_row' is each record in the grid CSV file which I posted the columns above (the location of each grid and neighboring grids) and 'crime_row' is a each crime incident that happened within the last year:
[image]

Comment: It seems for every grid, you iterate over every crime_row... you should describe what is crime_row and its relation with grid_row (for instance, why would they be equal they are the some object??). You should also consider giving a very minimal dataset and your reproducing script

Comment: Can those separate if statements (from grid_row[top],bottom, ...... , [bottomleft]) be chained as an if-else construct? I guess it does not affect your requirement by doing so.
And for countMonth, countWeek and countYear, make the condition *grid_row['id'] == crime_row['grid']* to be the first check, since it is more restrictive. Or, May be, it can be a high level 'IF' statement checking for *grid_row['id'] == crime_row['grid']* and then three inner IF statements for countMonth, countWeek and countYear. Hope it helps a bit in the performance.

Comment: @user753642 Yes I am iterating over each grid on the map and for each grid I am tallying up the amount of crimes that happened in the last week, last month, and last year for that specific grid. Crime_row is each individual crime incident that happened in the entire city of Nashville for the last year. I added a sample of what the crimes records look like above.

Comment: I expect I have misunderstood so correct me: each crime has a 'grid number' so why are you looking, for each grid cell, at every crime ?  Scan through the list of crimes, for each crime get the grid number, update the counters you want to keep, go to the next crime, ...

Comment: "and within each grid it loops through each crime (around 18,000)" I don't understand. Are there 18k _types_ of crimes and you are counting for each grid how often those crimes occur, or does each of those 18k correspond to one actual instance of a crime? In that case, can a crime be in more than one grid cell? Could you just create a map `{crime_id: grid_id}` instead of a CRIMExGRID table?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes you have the general idea...I was looping over data way more times then I needed to...the answer below solves this

Comment: @tobias_k Sorry about the poor wording but when I am saying each crime I mean each crime Incident... So I am passing in a Crime incident CSV that contains around 18,000 assault crime incidents for the city of Nashville in the last year and essentially I want to tally the totals for each individual grid (how many crim incidents happen inside each grid and around the neighboring grids).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do things can be simplified as

```
forall grid
  forall crimes
    if crime.cell == grid.cell
      do something
```

That complexity is `O(|grid| * |crimes|)`

if you have 3k crimes and 5k grid, this makes it 15e6 iterations

A better way is to iterate over the crimes and push any of them to its associated grid, stacking all the crimes having the same grid_index to... the same emplacement

```
gridIdxToCrimes = {} // to a grid_index you associate all the crimes

for crime_row in crime.iterrows():
  grid_index = crime_row['grid']
  if grid_index not in gridIdxToCrimes:
    gridIdxToCrimes[grid_index] = []
  gridIdxToCrimes[grid_index].push(crime_row)

forall grid_index, grid_row in grid.iterrows():
  topIndex = grid_row['top ']
  if topIndex in gridIdxToCrimes:
    # you get all the crimes above your current grid
    near += count(gridIdxToCrimes[topIndex])
```

This way you did O(|crimes|+|grid|) = 5k iterations

Comment: Yup this I what I was looking for... I knew it would be something with a dictionary like data structure to keep track and save having to do the nested loops. I am going to implement this idea real quick and get back to you.